# How to find out unpaired electron in S2 molecule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Theoretically electronic configuration and number of unpaired electron can be found out by using molecular orbital theory. But, practically I have seen only up to 20. For example, for Ne2[image]

But for S2 (32 electrons) how to find out the electronic configuration and number of unpaired electrons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The molecular orbital energy-level diagram of $\ce{S2}$ is given below:-[image]

([source](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Chemistry%3A_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/09._Molecular_Geometry_and_Bonding_Theories/9.8%3A_Second-Row_Diatomic_Molecules))

We can see  how close the energy the 3s and 3p atomic orbitals are because their energy separation will determine whether the  $\ce{π_3_{p}_{x,y}}$,  or the $\ce{σ_{3}_{p}_{z}}$ molecular orbital is higher in energy. Because the ns–np energy gap increases as the nuclear charge increases , the $\ce{σ_{3}_{p}_{z}}$ molecular orbital will be lower in energy than the $\ce{π_3_{p}_{x,y}}$ pair.

Each sulfur atom contributes 6 valence electrons, for a total of 12 valence electrons. Ten valence electrons are used to fill the orbitals through $\ce{π_{3}_{p}_{z}}$and $\ce{π_3_{p}_{y}}$, leaving 2 electrons to occupy the degenerate $\ce{π^{⋆}_{3}_{p}_{z}}$ and $\ce{π^{⋆}_{3}_{p}_{y}}$ pair. From Hund’s rule, the remaining 2 electrons must occupy these orbitals separately with their spins aligned. With the numbers of electrons written as superscripts, the electron configuration of $\ce{S2}$ is $\ce{(σ_{3}_{s})^{2}(σ^{⋆}_{3}_{s})^{2}(σ_{3}_{p}_{z})^{2}(π_{3}_{p}_{z,y})^{4}(π_{3}_{p}^{⋆}_{x,y})^{2}}$ with 2 unpaired electrons at the antibonding $\ce{π^{⋆}}$ orbital and thus is paramagnetic. The bond order is (8 − 4) ÷ 2 = 2, so we predict an $\ce{S=S}$ double bond.